# How to launch View Screenshots window on Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, testing, viewer

Hi I'm using Firebase for screenshots test in my project https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/test-screenshots#view_screenshots

After I have done the test and got to the completion. I cannot find this Screenshots Viewer

[image]

Has anyone done this part as same as me? Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You can see them at firebase crash report. Click on view source and you will find it under artifacts folder